Parachain stopped producing block with: Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback(“`NoElection` cannot do anything.”)
My config: Relay chain - Westend local (4 nodes), Parachain1 - Westmint (1 node), Parachain2 - Custom parachain (1 node)
I've launched the relay chain and parachains, then reserved the paraId for my parachains and connected the parachains to the relay chain. After that, the parachains started to produce and finalize blocks. However, after some time this error war thrown on the relaychain instance:
2024-04-29 09:59:54 [#172778]  Failed to finalize election round. reason ElectionError::Fallback("NoElectioncannot do anything.")

This error also occured on my parachains, and (assumingly) as a reult of that, the parachains stopped producing and finalising blocks. I tried to change the Fallback type from pallet_election_provider_multi_phase to type Fallback = onchain::OnChainExecution<OnChainSeqPhragmen>; However, it didn’t have any effect.
As I understand this error occurs because of the wrong validator selection on the relay chain. I launched 4 relay chain nodes and 2 parachains with 1 node for each. So when one of my relay chain nodes reboots, the election pallet can’t find right candidate and this error occurs. What settings are needed to ensure that this does not stop the production of blocks on parachains?
Steps to reproduce:

Launch Westend local relay chain, westmint local assethub parachain and my local custom parachain.
Block production initially worked well, I can interact with all the networks.
One of the relay chain nodes rebooted (it was running on Kubernetes).
One of the relay chain nodes rebooted (also running on Kubernetes).
Next, I received above error and parachain blocks stopped being produced.

How can I avoid this error from occurring, whenever one of my nodes reboots?
Thanks.

what do you mean by "westmint local parachain"? Is that a common good chain, like the assethub parachain?

In fact, yes, the westmint parachain it's asset hub chain. In this case, "local" means that the chain specification is "local".
